# Weird EOF behavior C++/VIM versus other IDEs

Tags: c++, vim, eof

I'm currently having problems with the EOF bit getting set correctly with my program.
The requirements for this program states that I will have two files that both have sorted lists of integers. The program should take in a number from both files and then compare these numbers. If one is less than the other, the smaller one will be outputted into another file and then another number will be drawn from the file it got its original number from.

So for example, let us say we have File 1 with the integers 1 3 5 9 with a new line between the integers instead of a white space and File 2 with 2 4 6 10. 1 should be compared to 2 and then 1 should be drawn into the output file. 1 will then be replaced by the number 3.

To help me solve this problem, I researched that EOF flag gets set after trying to draw in a number again AFTER the last number gets drawn in. This works perfectly in the code that I have below with input files created through VIM. After the last number from file 1 gets drawn in to the output file, the EOF bit is set and then the program brings in all of the numbers from the second file.

However, if I write identical input files in any IDE or text editor utilizing the same amount of newspaces between characters, I see some weird EOF behavior. When I write the same files in Sublime Text2 or Text Edit, the EOF bit gets set right when drawing in the last number. So lets say we use the command inputFile2 >> number2, EOF will be set to 1 right when this command draws in the final number 10. In text files created through VIM, if we use the command inputFile2 >> number2 with the last number being drawn in as 10, EOF will NOT be set to 1 until I run the command inputFile2 >> number2.

Does anyone have any knowledge of why there would even be a difference between the two editors? I've provided the code below. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
std::ifstream inputFile;
std::ifstream inputFile2;
std::ofstream outputFile;
bool conditionMet = false;

/* string variables for user input for files */
std::string inputName;
std::string inputName2;
std::string outputName;

/* int variables to hold the input from file */

int number1,
    number2;


inputFile.open("num1.txt");
inputFile2.open("num2.txt");
outputFile.open("output.txt);

inputFile >> number1;
inputFile2 >> number2;

/* loop until all of the numbers from files are in */
while (conditionMet == false)
{

    /* if the first number is less than or equal to the second number */
    /* check if the input file for number one is at the end of file */
    if (number1 <= number2)
    {

        /* if the end of file has been reached for the input file 1 */
        if (inputFile.eof())
        {
            /* put all of the numbers from input file 2 until the end of file for the second file */
            while (!inputFile2.eof())
            {

                outputFile << number2 << '\n';
                inputFile2 >> number2;
            }

            /* end the loop */

            conditionMet = true;

        }

        /* if the end of the file has not been reached then output number from input file 1 and then take in a new number */
        else if (!inputFile.eof())
        {
            std::cout << inputFile.eof() << "file1 eof before" << number1 << std::endl;
            outputFile << number1 << '\n';

            inputFile >> number1;
            std::cout << inputFile.eof() << "file1 eof after" << number1 << std::endl;
        }
    }

    /* if the first number is greater than the second number */

    else if (number1 > number2)
    {

        /* check if the input file for number two is at the end of file */
        /* if the end of file has been reached for the input file 2 */
        if (inputFile2.eof())
        {
            /* put all of the numbers from input file  until the end of file for the first file */
            while (!inputFile.eof())
            {
                outputFile << number1 << '\n';
                inputFile >> number1;
            }

            /* end the loop */
            conditionMet = true;

        }


    /* if the end of the file has not been reached, then output number from input file 2 and then take in a new number */

        else if (!inputFile2.eof())
        {
            std::cout << inputFile2.eof() << "file2 eof before" << number2 << std::endl;
            outputFile << number2 << '\n';

            inputFile2 >> number2;
            std::cout << inputFile2.eof() << "file2 eof after" << number2 << std::endl;
        }



    }



}

/* close all files */
inputFile.close();
inputFile2.close();
outputFile.close();

return 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `VIM` (and `emacs` too with my configuration) always end a file with a newline. This is done because VIM is line oriented and for C/C++ source code this is indeed mandated by the standard.

The fact that `VIM` is indeed quite specialized for possibly long files composed of relatively short lines can be seen by trying to work with a 10Mb file composed of one single line (don't do that).